# Commands in BAT files are not processed

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF

title Skype secondary Instance

echo A second instance of Skype will be started.
pause

"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary

exit
```

After running this BAT script the command windows does not close until the Skype program is not closed. Could you tell me why? And how to close the command window after the program has started.

Comment: What makes you think it *would* close? Each line in the script is executed *in turn*, any other behaviour would make scripting *very* problematic.

Comment: Indeed @Biffen, but why after the penultimate line (after the program has been opened), it doesn't go to _exit_ command? I couldn't find an explanation after a quick Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the START command.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
```

Although, I should think you don't even need a batch file. You could simply create a shortcut with `"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary` as the target.